# Session expires when generating pdf using itextsharp in asp.net

Tags: c#, itext

I have a web application which generates pdf documents and opens them on another tab. This works fine but after generating one or two pdf files successfully, on trying to generate another, session expires and am redirected to my login page. Please could possibly be the cause and what solution is there.
The application works perfectly on my localhost but when on a server, these issues come up..

please help

Comment: vague to answer, you need to elaborate more

Comment: after clicking "generate pdf" button, session expires and am redirected to my login page. what could possibly be the cause of that?

Comment: Is it possible that the PDF generation sometimes throws a fatal exception that kills the ASP.NET process, and in turn your open sessions (assuming you're using In-Proc)? Check your event viewer for unhandled exceptions, and see if you have any code in global.asax which might track major errors.

Comment: Please how do i go about that?

Comment: Start -> type "Event Viewer". Look in the Windows Logs->Applications section, and look for anything corresponding to the time you get logged out. For the global.asax, just look for anywhere you're handling OnError, and see what's going on there - I've seen some apps that handle an error by killing the session instead of trying to recover, so if that's happening to you, you can deal with it there.

Comment: where's this global.asax? Please note that this issue only happens on the server and not on my localhost. Thanks

Comment: If you had one, it would be at the root of your application, and it would just be called global.asax (probably alongside a global.asax.cs file). If you don't have one, then you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: so what do you think is likely to be the problem?

Comment: Like I said, the PDF generation may sometimes throw a major exception which kills the entire process and the sessions. If so, then you would likely see that in the Event Viewer, or see the code that kills the sessions in global.asax. I don't have any idea whether or not that's the case here, only you can determine that by reading your event viewer and global file. If you don't see anything there, then you'll need to continue troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't sound like a pdf-related issue. Check your Session expiration settings in your web.config.

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
   <sessionState timeout="30" />
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: my session timeout is 20minutes. The session gets expired just as i click the button.

Comment: Have you tried attaching the debugger and see what happens and on what point it falls over?

Comment: attaching the debugger where? Please pardon my questions.